# how to transform JSON array in ramda js?

Tags: json, transform, ramda.js

Input JSON

```
{
  'abc': [{
    'stores':[{
      'myproperty':true
    }],
    'list':[{
      'listname':'mylist',
      'listid': 'list1'
    }],
    'address': {
      'name':'george street'
    }
  }]
}
```

Output JSON

```
{
  'abc': [
    {
      myproperty: true,
      listname: 'mylist',
      listid: 'list1',
      address: 'george street'
    }
  ]
}
```

Need to consider only the first object in the array.

```
const transformArray = R.pipe(R.identity, R.applySpec({
    abc: R.pipe(R.prop('abc'), R.map(x => {
        return x.stores[0].myproperty
    }))
}));
```

New to Ramdajs, trying the build the functional code

Answer (score 2):

Use `R.evolve` transform the `abc` property, and then use `R.applySpec` with `R.path` to generate the internal object:

```js
const { evolve, applySpec, path } = R

const fn = evolve({
  abc: [applySpec({
    myproperty: path(['stores', 0, 'myproperty']),
    listname: path(['list', 0, 'listname']),
    listid: path(['list', 0, 'listid']),
    address: path(['address', 'name']),
  })]
})

const obj = {
  'abc': [{
    'stores':[{
      'myproperty':true
    }],
    'list':[{
      'listname':'mylist',
      'listid': 'list1'
    }],
    'address': {
      'name':'george street'
    }
  }]
}

const result = fn(obj)

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.28.0/ramda.min.js" integrity="sha512-t0vPcE8ynwIFovsylwUuLPIbdhDj6fav2prN9fEu/VYBupsmrmk9x43Hvnt+Mgn2h5YPSJOk7PMo9zIeGedD1A==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
```

If there might be multiple items in the `abc` array, use `R.map` as well:

```js
const { evolve, map, applySpec, path } = R

const fn = evolve({
  abc: map(applySpec({
    myproperty: path(['stores', 0, 'myproperty']),
    listname: path(['list', 0, 'listname']),
    listid: path(['list', 0, 'listid']),
    address: path(['address', 'name']),
  }))
})

const obj = {
  'abc': [{
    'stores':[{
      'myproperty':true
    }],
    'list':[{
      'listname':'mylist',
      'listid': 'list1'
    }],
    'address': {
      'name':'george street'
    }
  }]
}

const result = fn(obj)

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.28.0/ramda.min.js" integrity="sha512-t0vPcE8ynwIFovsylwUuLPIbdhDj6fav2prN9fEu/VYBupsmrmk9x43Hvnt+Mgn2h5YPSJOk7PMo9zIeGedD1A==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
```

Comment: See my answer for what I think is a simpler approach (without hardcoding the properties,)

Comment: Can we use R.propOr([], 'abc') to make sure the array is present before R.map?

Comment: You can use `R.when(R.is(Array), R.map(...))` to only call me map if it's an array. If you always want array, even if none exists, use  `R.ifElse(R.is(Array), R.map(...), R.always([]))`.

Answer (score 1):

We can write this fairly simply using a few Ramda functions:

```js
const convert = map (compose (mergeAll, flatten, chain (values)))

const input = {abc: [{stores: [{myproperty: true }], list: [{listname:'mylist', listid: 'list1'}], address: {name:'george street'}}]}

console .log (convert (input))
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.28.0/ramda.min.js"></script>
<script> const {map, compose, mergeAll, flatten, chain, values} = R      </script>
```

The `compose`d bit goes through these three steps:

```js
// after `chain (values)`
[[{myproperty: true}], [{listname: "mylist", listid: "list1"}], {name: "george street"}]
```

```js
// after `flatten`
[{myproperty: true}, {listname: "mylist", listid: "list1"}, {name: "george street"}]
```

```js
// after `mergeAll`
{myproperty: true, listname: "mylist", listid: "list1", name: "george street"}
```

Then we apply that to all properties of our input object with `map`.